# Make a difference Amount from 2 sheet using Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem to be solved. I have data from sheet 2016 and 2017. What I want to do is to make another sheet to calculate the difference money within 2016 and 2017. Please see the image link attached:

**Case 1:**
[image]

**Case 2:**
[image]

What I want to do is simply create the new sheet to compare each column except column A (column name). 
and another problem is the number of columns is not fixed. some case may have 1 column to be compared, another might have more. So I guess I need the number of columns to become a variable?

How is the idea to make the total (comparison) sheet using macro that can solve case 1 and case 2? please share your thought!

Comment: You should just use `VLOOKUP`s to return the columns you want to your total tab

Answer (score 0):

```
=INDEX ( Column I want a return value from ; MATCH ( My Lookup Value ; Column I want to Lookup against;0))
```

Use this formula to get the values in each column, then just subtract the results.